# jQuery Templates {{each}} - How to address the underlying objects individually?

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I got the data collection:

```
var messages = {
    0: {who:'aaa', age: 33, id: 2},
    1: {who:'bbb', age: 44, id: 3},
    // ...
};
```

I got the template:

```
<script type="text/jquery-template" id="chat-message-template">
    {{each $data}}
        <p id="id${$value.id}">${$value.who}</p>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Now I am rendering it and put the result to #container:

```
$('#chat-message-template').tmpl(messages).appendTo('#container');
```

And It works fine, BUT how do I get a single element (single 'p' element) of the rendered template to be able to update it?

`$('#oneOfParagraphsId').tmplItem();` OR `$.tmplItem('#oneOfParagraphsId')`
return all the collection of added paragraphs.

Yeah, I could walk through the collection and find the one I want, BUT, can I just somehow get a single item, not all the collection?

Even if I put a click event on each `<p>` and in handler do something like `$(this).tmplItem()` it still gives me all the p's of the template!

Comment: `{{ }}` is not restricted to Angular - and in this case it's correct, the plug-in uses them

Comment: `{{ }}` is used for a `LOT` of templating engines. @Tomalak

Comment: It's "jQuery Templates Plugin 1.0.0pre".

Comment: If you have just started, consider dropping jQuery templates in favor of an MVVM framework (personally I'm a fan of [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/)). It does all the templating, plus two-way value binding and makes jQuery largely superfluous in the area of UI generation. If switching frameworks is an option for you, I'll whip up an answer that shows how to use it with your input.

Comment: Thanks, I'll learn it by myself

Comment: Fair enough. BTW, I'm not saying that addressing the object belonging to an element created by jQuery Templates is impossible. The question as you have asked it is completely valid.